# Material-ui Dialog: manipulating the Escape button and mouse clicking outside of the dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I'm using material-ui's dialog: when a user presses "sign out" button, a dialog opens and there appears "yes" or "no" buttons asking whether the user realy wants to sign out or not.

When the user clicks the "escape" button or just clicks outside of the window, it signs him out - as if he pressed "yes". How can I control this? I want those to activate the "no" button.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, you could use a Confirmation Dialog variant of Mui `Dialog`. In this way you could force the user to click button `Yes` or `No` in your dialog.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-iz0hk?file=/src/index.js) I made a codesandbox example (inspired by [Mui Dialog page](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/))

Basically I made a simple `Button` with a component that calls Dialog:

```
return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <Button onClick={handleClickListItem}>sign out</Button>
    <ConfirmationDialogRaw
      classes={{
        paper: classes.paper
      }}
      keepMounted
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
    />
  </div>
);
```

The `ConfirmationDialogRaw` component:

```
function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, open, ...other } = props;

  const handleCancel = () => {
    // here just close the confirmation dialog
    console.log("stay in");
    onClose();
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    // here manage signout
    console.log("sing out");
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      disableBackdropClick
      disableEscapeKeyDown
      maxWidth="xs"
      aria-labelledby="confirmation-dialog-title"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogTitle id="confirmation-dialog-title">Sing Out</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography>Are you sure you want to exit?</Typography>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={handleCancel} color="primary">
          No
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleOk} color="primary">
          Yes
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

The magic is done by props `disableBackdropClick` and `disableEscapeKeyDown` on `Dialog` component.